# how to insert value into key json c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, json

Must enter values in a key of a Json but I can not implement, how I do?

Example:

```
{
    "name": "Allan",
    "lastname": "Zé Store",
    "type": "J",
    "street": "Rua Abdon Batista, 121",
    "emails": [
        {
            "email": "jose@zestore.com.br"
        },
        {
            "email": "marcos@zestore.com.br"
        }
    ],
    "phone": [
        {
            "number": "(11) 98765-4321"
        },
        {
            "number": "(47) 9876-5432"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to assemble an array inside the key?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Which key are you referring to? If you cannot describe in words, than post the current JSON, the data you have and the expected JSON. We are programmers - not brain readers ;o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is to define an array of object for the desired key. I hope this code will help you:

```
private void test()
{
    ojson myjson = new ojson();
    List<Email> myemails=new List<Email>();
    Email email = new Email();
    email.email = "";
    Email email2 = new Email();
    email2.email = "";
    myemails.Add(email);
    myemails.Add(email2);
    myjson.emails = myemails;
}


public class Email
{
    public string email { get; set; }
}

public class Phone
{
    public string number { get; set; }
}

public class ojson
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string lastname { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string street { get; set; }
    public List<Email> emails { get; set; }
    public List<Phone> phone { get; set; }
}
```